# Correct procedure for fixing broken WP sites after WP version update

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

What is the correct procedure for fixing a WP site that has broken due to a recent update to the latest WP version. Assuming there are no backups both locally or via the web host.

Is it a case of switching off plugins and switching themes to see if it is restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid reverting would depend on how major the upgrade was. A WP upgrade can change the database structure as well as the core code.

Your first step though should be to disable all plugins and see if the site runs without them. If so, enable them one by one until you find the problem one.

Same goes for your theme. Try one of the default themes to rule out a conflict with your own theme.

Make sure that your plugins and themes are on their latest versions too.

When I've had sites white-screen after an upgrade, those steps are usually enough to get to a fix.

If not, turn on PHP error display or logging and see where the problem apparently lies. This can be a mixed blessing as it may report a core file problem when really the issue is within a plugin or theme, hence the elimination of those earlier on. What you might see though is a compatibility issue with your hosting and the new version of WP.